# Using Property Rules to Simplify Set Expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been given a series of 20 set expressions which need to be simplified using property rules as part of an assignment.

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I've researched the subject online but none of the resources I've come across provide examples - which is really what I need before I can understand something.

Question No. 1:

$((Y \cup Y) \cap (X \cap Y)) \cap (X \cap (Y\cap X))$

Could somebody kindly provide me with a step by step explanation of how I should go about simplifying such an expression?

Comment: A first step would be noticing that $Y\cap Y = Y$, and $X\cap Y \cap X = Y\cap X$.

Comment: Likewise, I presume that Y$\cup$Y = Y. Correct?

Comment: Which property rules do those examples adhere to?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, $Y\cup Y = Y$. Two other useful identities: $$A\cap (A\cup B) = A \cup (A\cap B) = A.$$

Comment: I'm not sure what a "property rule" is. Perhaps it is a name that is only used by the professor in your class. If you have a list of things you are allowed to use, it would be helpful for you to post them.

Comment: You haven't told us what "property rules" you're working with, so nobody can answer the question "Which property rules do those examples adhere to?"

Comment: commutativity
 associativity
 idempotence
Distributivity


That's all we've been taught.

Comment: So you should add that information into your question, preferably with expressions illustrating each one. Eg:  Idempotence: $A\cap A=A, A\cup A=A$

Comment: Then, for instance, you can reduce the left part as $(Y\cup Y) \cap (X\cap Y) = Y\cap (X\cap Y) = Y\cap (Y\cap X) = (Y\cap Y)\cap X = Y\cap X$ which are applications of idempotence, commutitivity, associativity, and idempotence

Answer (score 1):

So, the "property rules" are associativity, commutativity, idempotence of $\cap$ and $\cup$, and distributivity of each over the other. Using these, you can simplify your expression as follows (skipping tedious intermediate steps):
$$\begin{align}
((Y \cup Y) \cap (X \cap Y)) \cap (X \cap (Y\cap X)) &= (Y\cup Y)\cap (X\cap Y\cap X\cap Y\cap X) \tag 1 \\
&= Y\cap (X\cap Y) \tag 2 \\
&= X\cap Y \tag 3 \\
\end{align}$$
(1) follows by associativity, (2) and (3) follow from their predecessors by associativity, commutativity and idempotence.